# How to show that congruent chords are equidistant from circle?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

I tried like  that  but did not get the required result.

[image]

Let the circle equation with center $C(-f,-g)$ is:

$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$.................(1)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=9in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn, twoside]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
 \clip(5.,3.) rectangle (11.1,8.4);
 \draw [->,line width=1.pt] (5.,4.) -- (11.,4.);
 \draw [->,line width=1.pt] (6.,3.) -- (6.,8.);
 \draw [line width=1.pt] (8.,6.) circle (1.7032909322837364cm);
 \draw [line width=1.pt] (6.296709067716264,6.)-- (8.450890034689387,7.642527983511332);
 \draw [line width=1.pt] (7.425867288241979,4.3963879430207005)-- (9.703175794491177,6.019804369703385);
 \draw [line width=1.pt] (8.450890034689387,7.642527983511332)-- (9.703175794491177,6.019804369703385);
 \draw [line width=1.pt] (6.296709067716264,6.)-- (7.425867288241979,4.3963879430207005);
 \draw [line width=1pt,dotted] (6.856167263763389,5.2054666102157405)-- (9.07995919044889,6.8273742809484705);
 \draw [line width=1.pt] (7.381953980879353,6.827481611880726)-- (8.60312548617443,5.2356156066094925);
 \draw (7.6,7.0) node[anchor=north west] {$d_1$};
 \draw (8.26,6.2) node[anchor=north west] {$d_2$};
 \draw (7.24,5.7) node[anchor=north west] {$d_3$};
 \draw (8.8,6.76) node[anchor=north west] {$d_4$};
 \draw (5.96,6.78) node[anchor=north west] {$A$};
 \draw (7.02,7.45) node[anchor=north west] {$P$};
 \draw (8.24,8.25) node[anchor=north west] {$B$};
 \draw (6.86,4.55) node[anchor=north west] {$D$};
 \draw (9.86,6.4) node[anchor=north west] {$E$};
 \draw (8.56,5.34) node[anchor=north west] {$Q$};
 \draw (7.46,6.35) node[anchor=north west] {$C$};
 \begin{scriptsize}
 \draw [fill=black] (8.,6.) circle (2.0pt);
 \draw [fill=black] (6.296709067716264,6.) circle (2.0pt);
 \draw [fill=black] (8.450890034689387,7.642527983511332) circle (2.0pt);
 \draw [fill=black] (7.425867288241979,4.3963879430207005) circle (2.0pt);
 \draw [fill=black] (9.703175794491177,6.019804369703385) circle (2.0pt);
 \draw [fill=black] (6.856167263763389,5.2054666102157405) circle (2.0pt);
 \draw [fill=black] (9.07995919044889,6.8273742809484705) circle (2.0pt);
 \draw [fill=black] (7.381953980879353,6.827481611880726) circle (2.0pt);
 \draw [fill=black] (8.60312548617443,5.2356156066094925) circle (2.0pt);
 \end{scriptsize}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If $AB$ and $DE$ are the two chords of circle as shown in figure, then the coordinates of the end points of the chords $AB$ and $DE$ are respectively:

$A(x_1,y_1), B(x_3,y_3), D(x_2,y_2), E(x_4,y_4).$

The length of the chord $AB$ and $DE$ are equal, therefore  $|AB|=|DE|.$

$\Rightarrow\sqrt{(x_3-x_1)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2}=\sqrt{(x_4-x_2)^2+(y_4-y_2)^2}$

The equation of line $AB$ with two points formula

$y-y_1=\dfrac{y_3-y_1}{x_3-x_1}(x-x_1)$

$\Rightarrow \boxed{(y_3-y_1)x-(x_3-x_1)y-(x_1y_3-x_3y_1)=0}$.........(1)

Similarly, the equation of chord $DE$ with two points formula using the end points is:

$\boxed{(y_4-y_2)x-(x_4-x_2)y-(x_2y_4-x_4y_2)=0}$.............(2)

The perpendicular distance from center $C(-g,-f)$\quad to the chord\quad $AB$\quad is:

$d_1=\dfrac{|(y_3-y_1)(-g)-(x_3-x_1)(-f)-(x_1y_3-x_3y_1)|}{\sqrt{(x_3-x_1)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2}}$

The perpendicular distance from center  $C(-g,-f)$ to the chord $AB$ is:

$d_2=\dfrac{|(y_4-y_2)(-g)-(x_4-x_2)(-f)-(x_2y_4-x_4y_2)|}{\sqrt{(x_3-x_1)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2}}.$

But the results $d_1\neq d_2$ at the end. Why?

Comment: Your tikz picture doesn't "pop up" as a graphics, at least on my screen...

Comment: You can just show that the length of a chord is a function of its distance from the center.

Comment: I have compiled your program and included the resulting figure in your text.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If two chords are congruent, then their "semi-chords" are also congruent.  Since the radii are also congruent, their distances to the center must be congruent by the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: @Mathew Daly Sir you are hundred percent correct but where is mistake in analytic proof that I have post. I am interested in that.